# Computing similarity matrix with mixed data

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, similarity, categorical-data

I have asked this question also on "Cross Validated" forum, but with no answer so far, so I am trying also here:

I would like to compute similarity matrix (which I will further use for clustering purposes) from my data (failure data from automotive company). The data consist of these variables:

START DATE + TIME (dd/mm/yyyy hh/mm/ss), DURATION (in seconds), DAY OF THE WEEK (mon,tue,...), WORKING TEAM (1,2,3), LOCALIZATION (1,2,3,...,20), FAILURE TYPE

From this, it is clear, that there are continuous and categorical data. What method would you suggest to calculate similarities between failure types? I think I can not use Euclidean distance, or Gowe's similarity. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That depends on your purpose.  For what purpose you want to define similarity?

Comment: Because I would like to perform cluster analysis on the data (hierarchical clustering)

Comment: You should give other a week to answer not **just 5 hours**. Don't cross-post, cross-validated was the better place to ask.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse If i post a c# question here, I usually get response to 5 minutes or so. I was honest and admitted that I am reposting this question, because on cross validated the taggs are not so well followed as here. I am not in a position to wait for a helpful answer for one week.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need an ad hoc function that represents your knowledge about what the data means in the real world. Presumably it will be mainly applying a weight to a continuous difference, and a 2D simple matrix for the discrete categorical variables.  But don't rule our censoring of extreme values or fuzzification.

Comment: I am affraid I don't know what you mean :) Can you be more concrete? Maybe a example would help. I would like to compute the matrix, so I will be able to perform hierarchical clustering and to find relationshops between failure types.